# Find the exponential Fourier transform of the given f(x)

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I attempted this problem, but my final answer does not seem simplified enough. The problem is that I don't know *how* to simplify it more and I lack the experience to be able to tell when it's ok to stop simplifying.

**My attempt:**

$f(x)=|x|, |x|<1 \quad ; \quad =0 \quad $everywhere else

$$g(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1 |x|e^{-iax}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1 xe^{-iax}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi} \left [\frac{xe^{-iax}}{-ia}|_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-iax}}{-ia} \right ]$$

$$=-\frac{1}{i\pi a} \left [e^{-ia} + \frac{e^{-ia}-1}{ia} \right ]$$

I'm new to Fourier transforming, so I'm not sure what a useable final answer looks like. Can this be simplified further?

Comment: You should have left it as an integral from $-1$ to $1$ and simple your answer into trig functions.

Comment: @JackyChong Why? This is an even function across the y-axis, so can't I just integrate from $0$ to $1$ and multiply by $2$?

Comment: Sure, but you could simplify your expression if you just stick to integration from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: But then how do I integrate the absolute value of $x$?

Comment: Let me write a short note in the answer section

Comment: [This is the output of the integral with the absolute value of x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+abs(x)e%5E(-iax)+from+x%3D-1+to+x%3D1). It doesn't look  simpler than my answer.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2+(-1%2Bcos(a)%2Ba+sin(a)))%2Fa%5E2&lk=1&rawformassumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^1_{-1}|x|e^{-iax}\ dx =&\  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^1_0 x e^{-iax} dx + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^0_{-1}-xe^{-ia x}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[\frac{xe^{-iax}}{-ia}\bigg|^1_0+\int^1_0 \frac{e^{-iax}}{ia}\ dx \right]- \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{xe^{iax}}{-ia}\bigg|^0_{-1}+\int^0_{-1}\frac{e^{iax}}{ia}\ dx\right]\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{-1+(1+i a) e^{-i a}}{a^2}\right]- \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[ \frac{1+i (i+a) e^{i a}}{a^2}\right]\\
=&\ \frac{-1}{\pi a^2}+\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{(1+ia)e^{-ia}-(-1+ia)e^{ia}}{a^2}\\
=&\ \frac{-1}{\pi a^2} +\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ia}+e^{-ia}}{a^2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2ia} = \frac{-1}{\pi a^2}+\frac{\cos a}{\pi a^2}+\frac{a\sin a}{\pi a^2}
\end{align}

Comment: @DougM https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%7Cx%7C+e%5E(-iax)+from+x%3D-1+to+x%3D1

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it further by using trig functions instead of the Euler notation. I would not recommend integrating from -1 to 1 since (you already seem to know) that integrating $|x|$ would have you dealing with the sgn(x) function and that's over-complicating the problem.